# Assign spring beans with annotations

Tags: java, spring, jsf, annotations, javabeans

I'm new with annotations, I'm trying the jsf(2.0) spring (3.1) integration, I could integrate the two frameworks but I don't have the viewScope in JSF because it isn't available. I want to use annotations to inject automatically spring beans in the jsf managedBean, but I can't because Spring only supports sessions and request scope beans.

I use a Util class who retrieves the bean. "SprigUtil.getBean('bean')". And manually retrieve spring beans when I need.

I want to do some like this

```
@CustomAnnotation('beanTest')
private Bean bean;
```

So, the bean attributte will be set with the beanTest bean.

My objective (leaving aside spring) is know how to do some like this

```
@assign('House')
private String place;
```

and when I call the `getMethod` obtain "House". instance.getPlace(), return 'House'

Note:
I Know about the @Autowired but I can't use that because ViewScope is not available in spring-jsf integration.

I read about implement the view scope manually but a want to try a different solution.

Edit:

My FacesConfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <application>
        <el-resolver>             org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

And my appContext

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
 
    <context:component-scan base-package="*" />
 
</beans>
```

My Spring bean

```
@Component
public class ProductService{

}
```

My Managed Bean

```
@Component
@Scope("request")//I need to use @Scope("view") but it doesn't exist
public ProductBean implements Serializable{
@Autowired
ProductService productoService;

}
```

If I use the jsf annotations @ManagedBean and @ViewScoped productService is not injected (is null)

Comment: could you please show your spring applicationContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject spring beans into view scoped managed beans by using [@ManagedProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/managed-bean-api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html)

For a spring component named B

```
@ManagedProperty("#{B}")
private B b;

public void setB(B b) {
this.b = b;
}
```

should work.

As for the code you have posted, Component is a Spring annotation, to use ViewScoped you must annotate your class with the ManagedBean annotation:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public ProductBean implements Serializable {
@ManagedProperty("#{productService}")
private ProductService productService;

public void setProductService(ProductService productService) {
    this.productService = productService;
  }
 }
```

You might want to check out the following link to better understand scopes in JSF 2.0 [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes)

Comment: i will try it.... But when I use @ViewScoped in the bean spring don't inject anything

Comment: Yes, in jsf 2 spring integration
5 types of bean scopes supported :Singleton, protoype, request,session and globalSession. I need the ViewScope but i can't use it, and if I use @ViewScoped annotation every Autowired in the mb don't work.

Comment: I am talking about your particular case :) Did you manage to inject a spring component into a i.e. RequestScoped managed bean?

Comment: Yes!, if I use a request scope (@Scope('request')) everything work fine.

In my case y hace the integration, but i need to inject spring beans in a mb in viewScope, but the viewScope is not avaliable. so i am triying to get work

Comment: I think you are mixing spring and jsf scopes, can you post your managed bean and spring bean code?

Comment: Ok, I will try that and post the results, thanks for the reply.